# Can dplyr join two data frames using a regular expression in by=?

Tags: regex, r, join, dplyr

Is there a way to join two data frames using dplyr's join operators, but using a regular expression instead of a straight by=c('foo' = 'bar')?

Something like:

```
people  <- data.frame(
     id = 1:10
   , emp = c("Caterpillar", "FEMA", "Community Hospital", "Gessert Grp.", "AT&T", "IBM Corp.", NA, "Smartguy Community College", NA, NA))



employers  <- data.frame(
     employerID     = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   , employerName   = c("Caterpillar Foundation", "Eli Lilly and Company Foundation Inc.", "Archer Daniels Midland Co", "IBM Corporation", "State Farm Co.  Foundation Matching Gifts")
   , employerRegexp = c("Caterpillar", "El *Lilly", "Archer *Daniels|ADM", "IBM", "State *Farm")
   )

peoplewRealEmployerNames  <- people  %>% 
     left_join(employers,by=c('emp' ~= 'employerRegexp')
```

Obviously, that `~=` won't really work, but maybe there's something similar?

Dplyr isn't a hard requirement, but it is the style I've written the rest of my code in, so it's my first choice for a solution.

Comment: You can use a `grep`-like regex function before the join to get the column names you want to use in the join and then look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125816/r-standard-evalation-for-join-dplyr/28125999#28125999) to find out how you can use character vectors as input for a dplyr join.

Comment: The code for 'employers' doesn't run. Please edit.

Comment: @docendo discimus , that FAQ was worth the price of admission for `setNames()` alone. I've been wondering if there was a way to do

    `names(foo)  <- c("foo","bar","baz")` 

within a pipeline for a month now! Doing this is so much better:

    `foo  %>% 
      someFunction()  %>% 
      setNames( c("foo","bar","baz")  %>% 
      moreFunctions()`

Comment: @crazybilly, that's nice to know. You think we can close this question as a duplicate of the other on then? Or do you want to answer it yourself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package `fuzzyjoin` does exactly this, using more or less the same syntax as `dplyr` does.

So, you just need to change the last two lines in your code to:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

peoplewRealEmployerNames <- people %>%
  regex_left_join(employers, by=c('emp' = 'employerRegexp'))
```

Comment: One note, for the sake of clarity: as the example shows, the regex should be in the right-hand data_frame. The column from the lefthand data frame is the string that will be searched.