# Using left_join from dplyr with merge variables specified

Tags: r, left-join, dplyr

I'm trying to use the left_join from dplyr with the merge keys specified

The function works fine, but the issue i'm having is that I would like to set the merge keys outside of the function (i.e. as variables client_1_key and client_2_key). Unfortunately I'm having issues with getting the syntax right. Any help would be appreciated

```
client_1_key <- "customer_hashed"

client_2_key <- "customer_identifier"

client_merged <- left_join(client_1_file, 
                       client_2_file, 
                       by = c("customer_hashed" = "customer_identifier"))
```

Example client_1_file:

Source: local data frame [24 x 1]

```
   customer_hashed
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Example client 2 file:

Source: local data frame [24 x 5]

```
    customer_identifier health_insurance pet_insurance life_insurance     car_insurance
     1                    1                Y             N              N             Y
     2                    2                N             N              N             Y
     3                    3                N             N              Y             N
     4                    4                Y             N              N             N
     5                   15                Y             N              Y             N
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: Standard evalation for \*\_join (dplyr)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125816/r-standard-evalation-for-join-dplyr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
 left_join(client_1_file, client_2_file,
        by= setNames(client_2_key, client_1_key))
 #     customer_hashed health_insurance pet_insurance life_insurance car_insurance
 #1               1                Y             N              N             Y
 #2               2                N             N              N             Y
 #3               3                N             N              Y             N
 #4               4                Y             N              N             N
 #5               5             <NA>          <NA>           <NA>          <NA>
```